# Recursive check for locked files

Tags: python

I'll have to move a large network directory with many sub-directories and thousands of files. A number of users work on these files on a daily basis. OS is windows.

The move itself (copy and delete) I'll do using `robocopy`.

Before starting the batch process of moving, I would like to check for locked files. In case some files or folders are locked, I won't bother starting the process.

`robocopy` has a dry run switch, but that doesn't check for locked files which would lead to an unsuccessful run.

I quickly came up with something like the below, in Python:

```
import os

is_locked=list()

for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('path/to/directory'):
    for filename in filenames:
        full_filename = os.path.join(root, filename)
        try:
            pf = open(full_filename, 'a')
            pf.close()
        except PermissionError:
            is_locked.append(full_filename)
```

Your opinion whether this is a good or bad way of doing it? Any general comment? 
Performance, etc?

Is it harmless to be opening these files?

--- edit ---

Summary of the most relevant comments:

- Break the loop when first locked file is found.

Comment: What protocol does the network mount use?

Comment: Also, do you care whether your method changes the file timestamp? You probably should..

Comment: This is a rather... significant change in code and functionality, which [isn't really the point of Code Review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1763/180641).  I don't know how best to proceed though...

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: This question [is being discussed on meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9381/37660)

Comment: Interesting discussion. I'm happy to comply, just need clearer guidelines. Since some comments pointed in the direction that the "complete and working code" rule was being broken, it was updated, then it clashed against the rule "don't edit code". ?=) Strangely, as it seems, this discussion took more importance and priority than the question itself.

Comment: Bug: only `PermissionError` exception is being checked. Need to handle other like `FIleNotFound` (walk takes some time to populate the list before being able to iterate through it)

Answer (score 3):

#### Bugs:

- After building your list, you throw it away without printing anything (and if not, please supply all your code)

#### Minor:

- [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) >>> os. It leads to much better readable code, and less boilerplate.
- `is_locked=list()` should be: `is_locked = []` Note spaces and the literal.
- `pf.close()` isn't a reliable statement. Instead, consider using something like `with open(full_filename) as pf: pass`
- `"path/to/directory"` is a magic variable. Make it a global constant instead.
- Use a `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard. Always.

#### Are you going to manually unlock all the files?

If not, you can just break after the first error and inform the user.

Comment: Nearly the entire of your answer is useless with regard to the actual code. This is why I made my comment. Also you shouldn't rely on your reasoning with regard to `pf.close()`.

Comment: You should not rely on the file being closed, even *with* the `close`. Because the exception will be raised before that line of code is reached. Only `with` can save you from that (or in this case putting the closing into a `finally` block).

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember who posted what comment earlier. But I'll update my answer to the `with` style, which is better indeed.

Comment: @Graipher I don't believe your are correct there, note how [`mgr = (EXPR)` from PEP 343 is the same as `pf = open(...)`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/#specification-the-with-statement), meaning that a `with` would do nothing that `.close` doesn't, in this instance. It may, however, ensure a file is closed if an error is raised between the creation and closure of the file.

Comment: @Peilonrayz: But you never reach the `close`, if the `open` raises an exception. However the `with` statement of course has internally a `finally: file.close()` statement in the `__exit__` method (or something equivalent), which ensures the file is closed even if an exception is raised. The file being closed in basically all cases with a `with`, but not otherwise, was the entire point of my comment.

Comment: @Graipher No it doesn't, did you look at my link? `mgr = (EXPR)` is clearly outside ___both___ `try` statements. What you're suggesting is impossible, as you have no file to close on.

Comment: @Peilonrayz I did, but I did not see what you are getting at. Do you mean that either the `open` succeeds, in which case the file will be closed by `close`, or the `open` call fails, in which case there is no file to close and it is not caught by the `with` either because it never gets that far? If that is the case, there are situations where the `with` is still needed to ensure the file is closed, basically all situations where something external triggers an exception between the (succesfull) `open` and `close` call, like a badly-timed Ctrl+C for example.

Comment: @Graipher When "the `open` raises an exception" then `with` and `.close` are the same - neither the `with` or the `.close` are reached. Yes, I already mentioned that in my first comment - "It may, however, ensure a file is closed if an error is raised between the creation and closure of the file."

Comment: @Gloweye: please consider editing your bug. It is a code fragment. The later handling of the list `is_locked` is irrelevant.

Comment: From the Code Review [ask] page, it is required to be complete code. That makes me assume that the code I read is complete, in which case it's an appropriate statement.